# Problem in a polynomial derivative calculator c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am doing a project for my school its a polynomial derivative calculator in c++
and I am having these problems:

(`^` is Exponentiation)

1. when user types `-x^n` it does not calculate the `-` in the outcome ex: `-x^4` -> `4x^3`
2. when user types `x^n` for a second time, or in a polynomial, it goes like this: `2x^5+x^4` -> `10x^4+0x^3`

```cpp
int main()
{
    char s[100];
    cout << " enter your Polynomial :  (use ^ for Exponentiation) ";
    cin.getline(s, 100, '\n');

    int i = 0;
    char za[20], t[20], z[20];
    
    while (true) {

        
        if (s[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }

        if (s[i] == '-' && s[i + 1] == 'x') {
            i += 2;
            if (s[i] == '^') {
                i++;
                int j = 0;

                if (s[i] == '-') {                 

                    for (j, i; s[i] != '+' && s[i] != '\0'; i++, j++) {

                        if (j != 0) {

                            if (s[i] == '-')
                                break;
                        }

                        t[j] = s[i];

                    }

                    t[j] = '\0';


                }
                else {

                    for (j, i; s[i] != '+' && s[i] != '-' && s[i] != '\0'; i++, j++) {

                        t[j] = s[i];
                    }
                    t[j] = '\0';

                }
                float tavan = atof(t);



                if (s[(i - j) - 3] == '+') {

                    cout << '+' << tavan << "x^" << tavan - 1;
                }
                else {
                    cout << tavan << "x^" << tavan - 1;
                }
                continue;

            }
            else {

                cout << "-1";
                continue;
            }
        }
         if (s[i] == 'x') {
             i++;
            if (s[i] == '^') {
                i++;
                int j = 0;

                if (s[i] == '-') {                

                    for (j, i; s[i] != '+' && s[i] != '\0'; i++, j++) {

                        if (j != 0) {

                            if (s[i] == '-')
                                break;
                        }

                        t[j] = s[i];

                    }

                    t[j] = '\0';
                

                }
                else {
                    
                    for (j, i; s[i] != '+' && s[i] != '-' && s[i] != '\0'; i++, j++) {

                        t[j] = s[i];
                    }
                    t[j] = '\0';

                }
                float tavan = atof(t);

                

                if (s[(i-j)-2] == '+') {
                    
                    cout << '+' << tavan << "x^" << tavan - 1;
            }
                else {
                    cout << tavan << "x^" << tavan - 1;
                }
                continue;
            }

            else {
                if (s[i - 2] == '+') {
                    cout << '+' <<"1";
                }
                else {
                    cout << "1";
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
        else {
            int x = 0;
            
            for (x, i; s[i] != '^'; i++, x++) {

                z[x] = s[i];

            }
            z[x] = '\0';
            i++;

            int j = 0;


            if (s[i] == '-') {                

                for (j, i; s[i] != '+' && s[i] != '\0'; i++, j++) {

                    if (j != 0) {
                        if (s[i] == '-')
                            break;
                    }

                    t[j] = s[i];

                }

                t[j] = '\0';

            }
            else {

                for (j, i; s[i] != '+' && s[i] != '-' && s[i] != '\0'; i++, j++) {

                    t[j] = s[i];
                }
                t[j] = '\0';

            }


            int k = 0;
            for (k; z[k] != 'x'; k++) {

                za[k] = z[k];

            }
            za[k] = '\0';

        

        float zarib = atof(za);
        float tavan = atof(t);

        zarib = tavan * zarib;
        tavan = tavan - 1;

        if (z[0] == '+') {

            cout << '+' << zarib << "x^" << tavan;
        }
        else {
            cout << zarib << "x^" << tavan;

        }

    }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seriously I would hand it in as it is. The code is completely unstructured, (e.g. not a single function other than main, excessively complex loops). There's a serious danger that you will make things worse by tinkering with it when you are up against a deadline. Next time you have to write some code, try breaking the problem down into smaller pieces and solve each piece with its own function. Code is much more manageable that way.

Comment: john is right. Your code has a lot of blocks these may convert in functions, variables spreaded etc. It is hard to read and make it more error-prone .Making this review will be easier to you find the problem and maybe, with a better structured code you can figure out by yourself the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use list to make it easier to insert data. Also, a better structured code will be helpful to find problems. You could refer to the following code;

```
typedef struct node
{
    float coef;
    int expn;
    struct node* next;
} PLOYList;

void insert(PLOYList *head, PLOYList *input)
{
    PLOYList *pre, *now;
    int signal = 0;
    pre = head;
    if (pre->next == NULL)
    {
        pre->next = input;
    }
    else
    {
        now = pre->next;
        while (signal == 0)
        {
            if (input->expn < now->expn)
            {
                if (now->next = NULL)
                {
                    now->next = input;
                    signal = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    pre = now;
                    now = pre->next;
                }
            }
            else if (input->expn > now->expn)
            {
                input->next = now;
                pre->next = input;
                signal = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                now->coef = now->coef + input->coef;
                signal = 1;
                free(input);
                if (now->coef == 0)
                {
                    pre->next = now->next;
                    free(now);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}

PLOYList *create(char ch)
{
    PLOYList *head, *input;
    float x;
    int y;
    head = (PLOYList*)malloc(sizeof(PLOYList));
    head->next = NULL;
    scanf("%fx^ %d+", &x, &y);
    while (x != 0)
    {
        input = (PLOYList*)malloc(sizeof(PLOYList));
        input->coef = x;
        input->expn = y;
        input->next = NULL;
        insert(head, input);
        scanf("%fx^%d+", &x, &y);
    }
    return head;
}

PLOYList *def(PLOYList *head)
{
    PLOYList *p;
    p = head->next;
    while (p)
    {
        p->coef = p->expn;
        p->expn = p->expn--;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return head;
}

void print(PLOYList *fun)
{
    PLOYList *printing;
    int flag = 0;
    printing = fun->next;
    if (fun->next == NULL)
    {
        printf("0\n");
    }
    while (flag == 0)
    {
        if (printing->coef > 0 && fun->next != printing)
            printf("+");
        if (printing->coef == 1);
        else if (printing->coef == -1)
            printf("-");
        else
            printf("%f", printing->coef);
        if (printing->expn != 0)
            printf("x^%d", printing->expn);
        else if ((printing->coef == 1) || (printing->coef == -1))
            printf("1");
        if (printing->next == NULL)
            flag = 1;
        else
            printing = printing->next;
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```